# change the reference format for subfigures

Tags: floats, cleveref

I am using `\subfigures` to plot multiple figures on two pages:

```
\begin{subfigures}
\setlength\figureheight{4cm} 
\setlength\figurewidth{5cm}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\input{Figure2a_1.tikz}
\input{Figure2a_2.tikz}
\input{Figure2a_3.tikz}
\caption{}
\label{fig2a} 
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\input{Figure2b_1.tikz}
\input{Figure2b_2.tikz}
\input{Figure2b_3.tikz}
\caption{}
\label{fig2b} 
\end{figure}
\label{fig2}
\end{subfigures}
```

So the labels of these two subfigures are 'Figure 2a' and 'Figure 2b'.

In the text, I want to refer to them alltogether as 'Figure 2' and let the reference point/link to 'Figure 2a'. Is there a way to achieve this? Is `cleveref` helpful on this?

Many thanks!

Comment: What package defines the `subfigures` environment?

Comment: I assume, if the environment is called `subfigure(s)`, that there is a `subfigure(s)` counter. The counter output format is counted in the command `\thesubfigure(s)` then. It can be changed to basically anything then, by redefining `\thesubfigure` or `\thesubfigures` (Although I believe that it should read `subfigure`, not `subfigures`!)

Comment: I used `\usepackage{subfloat}` in order to use `subfigures`. I am using `subfigures` not `subfigure`.

Answer (score 2):

[I would normally add this as a comment but don't have enough rep on LaTeX Stack to do so…]

Have you tried using `minipage` in combination with the `subcaption` package?  For instance, the following might work:

```
\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
    \centering\large A
    \subcaption{A subfigure}\label{fig:1a}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
    \centering\large B
    \subcaption{Another subfigure}\label{fig:1b}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{A figure}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
```

Or you could redefine the way the figures were referenced (still need the `subcaption` package) using:

```
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\thefigure}
```

which should change the label shown in the text.  I don't think this will affect the label shown in the, but to be sure, you can use the `\subref` command and try:

```
\captionsetup{subrefformat=\thefigure}
```

I think that will work.

Comment: Sorry I tried to use the `subcaption` package but when compiling the file, it returns: "Package `subcaption` Error: This package can't be used in cooperation (subcaption) with the `subfigure` package." And when trying `minipage` some other error message pops up...

Comment: But it's okay. I just re-wrote the main text so that I cite both Figure 2a and Figure 2b. Not a crucial issue. Thanks a lot for your help.